# Routing Error for jquery plugin in rails 3.1.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am using Fancy box (jquery plugin ) to view video files in my application. I have placed the plugin under vendor -> Javascripts -> javascripts.

but when I run the development server I get the following errors:

Note: I have not modified anything: I just moved the files from my desktop and placed them under vendor/javascript  folder

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"):

Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"):

Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)
```

Comment: Folder jquery.fancybox-1.3.4 located in public dir?

Comment: Its in the Vendor/Javascripts/Fancybox

Comment: Duplicate by same user — [Rails 3.1.3 unable to access the file inside assets/javascripts folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274418/rails-3-1-3-unable-to-access-the-file-inside-assets-javascripts-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the gem 'fancybox-rails'