# Rails 3.1.3 unable to access the file inside assets/javascripts folder

Tags: jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have put fancybox (jquery plugin ) inside the assets/javascripts/includes/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4

Before this location i also tried to put it under /vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery directory.

I am getting this weird error & why isn't rails able to get the particular file when its right there.

-------------  Development Log ----------------

Started GET "/vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-25 13:30:42 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"):

Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)

-------------- Log 2 -------------------------

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/assets/javascripts/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the fancy box gem https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't load your `*/assets/javascripts` tree automatically, just the files in that directory. And by default, it will only precompile `application.js` and anything with a non `.js` extension.

I would recommend you rename the fancybox file to just `fancybox-1.3.4.js`. With Rails 3.1, assets are concatenated and minified before output, so there's not much need to even use the minified version, though it won't hurt anything if you do.

You should put jQuery plugins directly in `vendor/assets/javascripts/`, then include them into the appropriate file (probably `application.js`) in `app/assets/javascripts`, like so (assuming application.js):

```
//= require jquery
//= require fancybox-1.3.4
//= [any other requires here]
//= require_self
```

Then you use `javascript_include_tag 'application'` in your layout. Voila!

Comment: Inside application.js i pasted  //= fancybox-1.3.4.  & i put the fancybox files in the required folder. It still gave me this error. I know that file is there. Pasted at top

Comment: Earlier i was unable to reach the asset file from localhost:3000/assets/name_of_file. But then i directly placed the contents under vendor/assets/fancybox-1.3.4

Comment: This is wrong: `vendor/assets/javascripts/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js`. You do *not* want a `fancybox-1.3.4` directory.

Comment: So, you are saying that i should never use .js extension?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said "You do *not* want a `fancybox-1.3.4` directory." Reading comprehension goes a long way.

Comment: @coreyward I am using 'fancyboxgem'. Still the images doesn't show up on the browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276094/rails3-1-3-error-gems-actionpack-3-1-3-lib-action-dispatch-middleware-templ