# Rails3.1.3 Error :   /gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use gem 'fancybox-rails' & have updated the files as required by gem.

I created a controller and a view to generate a page with video links.

I am using Rails 3.1.3. I have updated my bundle using "bundle update" & everything seems to be in line but I am getting the following error.

Here is the whole code for the application  :  https://github.com/jaipratik/i_have_removed_it

I am getting the following errors.

Output - Development log (may be useful )

```
Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (3.7ms)
```

-----Error: -----------------------------

```
Rendered /Users/jayparteek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@default/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)
```

Comment on above error: i have updated the gems 'gem update'

-------Error: ----------------------------

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/cycling_small.jpg"):
```

Comment on above error: This image is placed inside assets/folder/.... I can access this image
via http://localhost:3000/assets/cycling_small.jpg

------------- Images doesn't show up -----------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This silly error sucked up a lot of my time. Let me tell you one time solution for it.

The only reason you get this error is YOUR MISTAKES in the code.

I was able to display my images on the browser by using the absolute path to the  source

I dont know why   doesn't work. For me its still a mystery.

Suggestion: try using Firebug.